# SQL Server database collation for general use in ASP.NET applications when CultureInfo='zh-CN(S)'?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, localization

Suppose I go for 'zh-CN' in

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
```

which SQL server collation should I use for a general use database, aiming at the Chinese language used in People's Republic of China?

The choice is so extensive:

[image]

Comment: if you had to choose an option for any language, would you choose case sensitive or not? would you choose accent sensitive or not? Well, it depends on what youu need or you want. In Chinese you face exactly the same problem. There is no best or worst option... there are just options, and you have to choose what you need. So, the answer is "there is no best option".

Comment: I still had to chose some option, so opted for 'Chinese_PRC_CI_AS'